# What's the actual cost of defining new function within react render method?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to clarify the pros/cons of having a new function declaration within react's render method.

Consider a render method like the following:

```
  render () {
    return (<SomeComponent somePropWithoutEventBind={() => console.log('not so dangerous?')} />)
  }
```

In the above example, `somePropWithoutEventBind` doesn't bind to a DOM event: react will check for prop changes and every time render is called this prop has changed - because it's a new function - so it never matches the previous, this is expensive but nothing tremendous.

Now in this case

```
  render () {
    return (<input onChange={() => console.log('dangerous?')} />)
  }
```

onChange `prop` **does** bind to DOM (doing something like `addEventListener`) so every render will have to `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` again? Is this the main reason behind avoiding to declare functions inside the render method?

If possible, please justify your answer pointing to react source code.

Comment: It's a consideration, but ultimately it's just the overhead of creating a bunch of new functions. Here, by "a bunch", I mean "however many times the component re-renders". Which can be a lot. The more important consideration is the content of the function, specifically `this` references.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton, but what about the props that bind to DOM? Does react optimizes for that for us? how does that work? Because that worries me the most, I supposed re-attaching event listeners must be a LOT more expensive than declaring new fns.

Comment: This is discussed in the React event handling docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. I more or less stand behind what I originally said--it's an issue, but not a huge one IRL. If whatever I was doing re-rendered a lot, or had demanding performance requirements, it'd be something I'd pay attention to, otherwise I wouldn't. That said, I generally use either ctor binding or instance arrow functions anyway, because for me it's easier to read and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason of avoiding defining new functions in render is to avoid **over** rendering.

Consider bind a new function onto a DOM element (**react element** not real DOM) like so: `<button onClick={_ => this.setState({ hide: true })}>Hide Me</button>}` there's almost none cost at all, since DOM elements gets re-rendered anyways. (site note: react doesn't use native DOM events like add/removeEventListener, it uses [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) and your code targets virtual DOM aka react element not real DOM)

However for a custom components (In large codebase we typically have lots of complex Container Component composed of Functional/Class Child Components. Let's say you have something like

```
render() {
  // you won't run into unnessary re-render issue 
  // when you use `onClick={this.handleClick}` since the function reference doesn't change
  // while most perf tricks done by react bindings are relying on shallow compare of props/state
  return (
    <ComplexContainer onClick={_ => this.setState({ forceReRender: true})}>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2>
        <NestedChild1 />
        <NestedChild2 />
      </Child2>
    </ComplexContainer>
  )
}
```

If you do this way, this will cause the whole render tree starting from ComplexContainer to re-render, this may have notable negative perf impacts, but you will need DevTools profiling to benchmark.

In fact, the real thing i wanna say is: **it might not be that huge as you concern, avoid premature optimization can be more important**. Give this awesome reading material a shot: [React, Inline Functions, and Performance](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578)

<sub>A bit more info regarding react synthetic event system here, it's simply a wrapper of native DOM events to normalize the subtle differences of events among different browser vendors. The API would be the same `event.preventDefault()`/`event.preventPropagation()` etc works as it is, but you get cross-browser compatibility for free. Regarding how it works internally please see [event delegation](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, good answer!
Could you elaborate on how the synthetic events layer works? How it avoids re-binding to the DOM, etc. That's the only missing piece. Thanks

Comment: @enapupe Updated. Feel free to tell me if you need more info on this :)

Comment: > Event delegation: React doesn't actually attach event handlers to the nodes themselves. When React starts up, it starts listening for all events at the top level using a single event listener. When a component is mounted or unmounted, the event handlers are simply added or removed from an internal mapping. When an event occurs, React knows how to dispatch it using this mapping. When there are no event handlers left in the mapping, React's event handlers are simple no-ops.